# server time drift not fixed by ntp.conf

Tags: server, ntp

This question was asked a lot in the past, but since ntpdate has been depricated, I'm having issues finding answers that work via ntp.conf.  I've read a lot about setting a cron job for ntpdate is a bad idea now, so that answer won't work for me.

My server time (ubuntu 14.04 server) is drifting quite a bit, and I have a time server I'm using locally.

In my ntp.conf file I have my server listed like this

```
server 192.168.1.25 iburst burst minpoll 4 maxpoll 4
```

Despite these settings the watchdog timer run from

```
ntpdc -c loopinfo
```

never resets and my drift keeps getting larger and larger.

To sum up my question, why isn't my /etc/ntp.conf file actually doing anything?
More info: This is a Ubuntu 14.04 VM running on Hypver-V and is used as a Redmine server.

output of ntpq -p (not sure if typo, but no q option)

```
    remote           refid        st  t  when  poll  reach   delay   offset   jitter
   ===================================================================================
    myother.server 192.168.1.26    2  u   2    16    377     0.607   0.808     4691.46
```

Comment: Are you able to set the time using `ntpdate`?

Comment: Please add the output of `ntpq -qp`.

Comment: When I run ntpdate -u 192.168.1.25 I get the offset, and I'm assuming it also sets the time correctly.  However, when I try to set ntpdate up in cron, it won't run.  I'm not sure why, but since it is depricated, I didn't really worry about it.

Comment: The requested output is shown above.

Comment: With that output it is clear it thinks your source is Stratum-2, which is very good.  And surprising, since you are not using time.nist.gov.  Here is a reference Q&A that talks to this subject, suggesting you reference the master clock directly:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/972799/how-do-i-set-ubuntu-to-use-the-primary-time-server-time-nist-gov/972800#972800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching, the problem was obvious.  It wasn't actually a problem with the machine itself, but with hyper-v.  Apparently Hyper-v is a terrible choice for linux virtualization.  It's a known problem that doesn't appear to have a fix other than just running something on the guest Linux machine.

I use this cron job

```
0 * * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate 192.168.1.x
```

obviously the 192.168.1.x represents the ntp server.  This fixed my time every hour.  The documentation on how hyper-v has a hard time keeping time with linux guests is noted in several places such as [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/10041/hyper-v-machine-drifts-time-all-over-even-with-ntp), and [here](http://www.hardanswers.net/correct-clock-drift-in-centos-hyper-v).