# How do I set Ubuntu to use the primary time server time.nist.gov?

Tags: time, ntp

FileZilla is spending way too much time copying files that are already there because the clocks on my systems vary too much.

**I want to set them all to the Master Clock (like WWV)**

According to the NIST page, the National Bureau of Standards suggests using time.nist.gov as the address that will reach a working system among all of the Stratum-1 and 2 servers available:

[NIST Internet Time Servers](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi)

Obviously, Ubuntu is using time server pools, like Microsoft does, which are many hops away from the master clock source.

My question is in the title:  How do I set Ubuntu to use the primary time server time.nist.gov?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Time server settings are saved in `/etc/ntp.conf` so open your favorite editor and make this simple change.

```
sudo vi /etc/ntp.conf
```

The relevant section looks something like this (It may say ubuntu instead of debian, but it is the same problem either way):

[image]

**So all you need to do is change it to look like this on all the relevant computers:**

[image]

**then reboot them.**

Voila, the systems are now all using the NIST/NBS Master Clock to synchronize.  Stratum 1 is the primary source, and Stratum-2 are a single hop away from it.

The pools are anywhere from 12-16, just like Windows when it uses pools.

You can verify that it is working at Level 1 by using this command:

```
ntpq -p
```

Which gave me this output:

[image]

**FileZilla is now running unbelievably faster as it is able to skip more files! 
Amazing difference.  Time synchronization is an excellent experience.**

This is the best that can be attained via the Internet.

**`time.nist.gov` is a load balancer that will find the best server for any particular location.**

---

If you want your system to announce the time to you on the hour, you can use this procedure:

[16.04 LTS How to make the system announce the time at the top of the hour with eSpeak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977613/16-04-lts-how-to-make-the-system-announce-the-time-at-the-top-of-the-hour-with-e?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

**In Windows this same change is even easier.  Just click on the clock and follow the prompts to change the Internet time to time.nist.gov then update.**

By doing that, even transfers into and out of Windows (for hard drive backups) are a LOT faster as it skips files with the same creation date on both sides.

This has a pleasant side-effect of minimizing the amount of time it takes to ROBOCOPY out to a backup drive, too.

---

If you want Windows to announce the time to you at the top of the hour, use this procedure:

https://superuser.com/questions/1268702/how-to-make-windows-speak-the-time-at-the-top-of-the-hour

---

### Once all the systems are set to this time source you can hear them announce the time all at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is quite good but it describes the `ntp` package which isn't installed by default. Nowadays Ubuntu uses `systemd` which has a piece of code for time synchronization. You need to edit `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` file and change the line `#NTP=` to `NTP=time.nist.gov`. After that you need to apply the changes:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd
```

And check the status:

```
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
    systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
    systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
    systemd-timesyncd[30976]: Synchronized to time server 132.163.96.3:123 (time.nist.gov).
```

You can get more information by:

```
$ man 5 timesyncd.conf
$ man 8 systemd-timesyncd.service
```