# 16.04 LTS How to make the system announce the time at the top of the hour with eSpeak

Tags: 16.04, cron, espeak

Past versions of Ubuntu had speech built in.

Searching in Unity I can't find anything with the words "speak" nor "speech" that are relevant for TTS

My plan is to have `cron` jobs speak so I can leave the monitor shut off.

Beginning with having it do a time announcement each hour.  It is OK if it is not perfectly precise to the second.

So how can I make 16.04 LTS speak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my project, `cron` jobs that can talk, `espeak` is the simplest.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install espeak
```

It can announce the time with `/home/me/scripts/saytime`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "\`$(date +%H)\` Hundred" | espeak
```

Then set it into crontab like so:

```
export EDITOR=gedit
crontab -e
```

...add this line:

```
00 * * * * /home/me/scripts/saytime
```

---

For more details about espeak itself:

[How to text-to-speech output using command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501910/how-to-text-to-speech-output-using-command-line/977616#977616)

Comment: Stop spamming links to your posts, please.

Comment: @SDsolar I would suggest adding how you added the script to your crontab as well, that way it's a more complete answer.

Comment: Great idea.  You can now see it above.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to initialize sound in crontab temporary shell to get sound.

So you can initialize sound in crontab or at least in script that is called from crontab.